# How do I install tagainijisho on 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I want to install a software called tagainjisho and the website redirected me to [tagainijisho source package on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tagainijisho/).
How can I install that in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: The `tagainijisho` package was dropped from Debian in early 2019 and from Ubuntu after 19.04. The upstream developer(s) seem to have abandoned the project. We don't recommend installing abandonware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that the application is [Qt4-based](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tagainijisho). So you can not install it on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS because of unsatisfied dependencies.

But you can compile [newest Qt5-based](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tagainijisho-git) [version](https://github.com/Gnurou/tagainijisho) by yourself and then install by using commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git qt5-default libsqlite3-dev desktop-file-utils cmake qttools5-dev

cd ~/Downloads/
git clone https://github.com/Gnurou/tagainijisho.git

cd tagainijisho
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

and then launch it by `tagainijisho` command or by using [image: Tagaini Jisho] *Tagaini Jisho* launcher.

Comment: Thank You So Much! Tagainijisho is working now!